# will have to grammar

Tags: grammar

What is the English Grammar of the phrase bellow?

> You will have to take up your business with me

I haven't seen the phrase

> will have to

before.

By the way, when should we use that Grammar?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have under "auxiliary verb", definition 2. "have to" = "be compelled/obligated/required to"

Comment: I got it, forces.

Comment: You haven't seen it before because it's not a constituent -- not a grammatical unit, but part of three separate verb phrases: "will have to ... " / "have to ... / "to ...".